# How to add field in "stock.quant.tree"

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i want to add a custom field in stock.quant named "designation2" which  I use odoo 9 and I want to add a custom field in "stock.quant" which takes as value the product description entered when creating the price request and purchase order ? 
I have created a new custom module and i added a new field in stock.quant but i don't know how to get the value of the product description ?? Any help please  ?

[image]

**stock_quant_tree.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="stock_quant_tree_designation" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.quant.tree.designation</field>
        <field name="model">stock.quant</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_stock_quant_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='qty']" position="after">
                        <field name="designation2"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

**stock.py**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import tools

import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools.translate import _
class StockQuantTreeDesignation(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'stock.quant'
_columns = {
'designation2':fields.char( string="Désignation",required=True,select=True), }
```

Comment: any help please ??

Comment: odoo 9 and you are using OSV ?

Comment: Use Models instead osv

Comment: I've added fields in odoo10, if you are interrested reply me

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana Could you help me please ? i 'm gonna be thankfulfor that

Comment: I'll set a odoo10 code

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana Ok Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code may it's help you :

**Python code :**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class StockQuants(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.quant'

    designation2 = fields.Char(compute="_compute_vehicle_count", string="Désignation")


@api.one
def _compute_vehicle_count(self):
    designation_list = self.env['purchase.order.line'].search([('product_id', '=', self.product_id.id)])  # here make sure the name of class 'purchase.order.line'
    self.designation2 = designation_list[-1].name
```

**XML Code :**

```
<record id="stock_quant_tree_designation" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.quant.tree.designation</field>
        <field name="model">stock.quant</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_stock_quant_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='lot_id']" position="after">
                <field name="designation2"/>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it displays nothing